# Stucked with error: Argument 2 passed to db_query() must be an array

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I`m updating from 6.x to 7.x. I have updated core, modules and now working on updating a theme. For this purpose I downloaded ZEN as a base theme and started to develop a new sub-theme (from the theme of previous version). And with this new "sub-theme" selected I get this errors:

Recoverable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to db_query() must be an array, null given, called in ~modules/php/php.module(80) : eval()'d code on line 11 and defined in db_query() (line 2342 of ~includes/database/database.inc).

I tried to switch to garland - on garland everything is ok.
I tried to switch to bartik - and get same error.
So the problem is not in theme (I checked my new sub-theme couple times).
I checked all blocks (to find PHP with error code), corrected some problems, but still got this error.
I also tried to switch off almost all blocks in bartik (except for 'navigation' and 'Main page content'), but still got this error.
I can`t find out there is problem. Is there any method how can I detect problem place to be able to fix it?
For now I checked all blocks, all themes, all content with php filter. After that I cleared cache and still got this error. And the most amazing thing that I get no error with garland.
What can I do to find out where is problem?

Comment: Turn off the PHP filter module - do you still have the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 6's db_query function expects the first argument to be a parameterized query, and the rest of the arguments to be replacements for them in the correct order.

Drupal 7, however has PDO support and ye db_query function's second argument should be an array of `placeholder` => `value` pattern.

```
 db_query('SELECT * from somewhere where something = :that ', array(':that' => 'beer'));
```

Now you know what is wrong so find this in your theme.